# Is it possible to make Single Page Application and MPA at the same time?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel and vue.js to make a SPA. So my routes looks like this:

In my `routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/{any}' , 'SinglePageController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

and then, the entire route will be handled by the `vue router`.

However, I decided to make a Multiple Pages(for my SEO) on other Pages while the SPA is for the loggedin users only.

I'm going to add another route in `web.php` but it returns 404 .

```
Route::get('/guests', 'GuestController@index');
```

[Note that I have `GuestController` and blades]

Is it possible? If so, please give me hints. I tried to search on google but haven't found.

Comment: look into this https://ssr.vuejs.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just have to place your route for `/guests` *before* your more general `/{any}`. Remember, Laravel check routes from top to bottom and the first matched will be used.

```php
Route::get('/guests', 'GuestController@index');
// other specific routes
// ...
Route::get('/{any}' , 'SinglePageController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```